# a clipboard dumping machine for OSX

Tags: macos, applescript, clipboard

I wanted to make a small app in applescript that polled the clipboard for changes and upon detecting any, dumped the contents of the clipboard into a text file. here is the code i came up with, it creates the file but nothing gets written into it. what am i doing wrong?

```
property oldvalue : missing value

on idle
    local newValue
    set newValue to the clipboard
    if oldvalue is not equal to newValue then
        try
            tell application "Finder"
                try
                    set the_file to "/Users/xxx/Documents/dump2.txt" as POSIX file as alias
                on error
                    set the_file to (make new document file at ("/Users/xxx/Documents/" as POSIX file as alias) with properties {name:"dump2", text:""})
                end try
            end tell

            try
                open for access the_file with write permission
                write newValue to file the_file starting at eof
                close access the_file
            on error
                try
                    close access the_file
                end try
            end try

        end try

        set oldvalue to newValue

    end if

    return 1 
end idle
```

Comment: Curious what exactly the point of this application is.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open for access` also accepts a POSIX path as text as an argument, and the path specified as an argument does not have to exist. Your script didn't work because `make new document file` returns a Finder file object, and the `as POSIX file as alias` part always resulted in an error.

```
property old : ""
on idle
    set new to the clipboard
    if new is not old then
        set old to new
        if new does not end with linefeed then set new to new & linefeed
        set b to open for access "/tmp/clipboard.txt" with write permission
        write new to b as «class utf8» starting at eof
        close access b
    end if
    return 1
end idle
```

`as «class utf8»` is needed because `write` still uses the primary encoding (like MacRoman or MacJapanese) by default. `as Unicode text` would be UTF-16.